# How could I find the Kubernetes Pod restart reasons

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In have scaled my Pods to 20 in my cluster and when I see the next day the few of the scaled Pods were recreated.

When I say Pod recreated, it is getting deleted and created freshly and the timestamp of the recreated Pod and the scaled Pods vary.

I was unable to find the reasons for the recreate of the Pods.

I could not find which Pod went for a recreate as the Pod is deleted and gone away. There are no logs in the journalctl regarding which Pod got recreated. Is there any way I can debug further to find the reason for the Pod recreate? Or what might be the reason for the PODs getting deleted?

Note: I have readiness and liveness probes defined, but these probes would act on container and would not lead to Pod recreate in my understanding.

Comment: Those liveness probes are _designed_ to kill off bogus Pods, that's their job in life, but you are correct that a liveness fail will cause a restart event, and will not change the `.metadata.name` of the Pod, only its restart count. It is also supremely likely that if the Pod names are changing, it's due to a ReplicaSet change, not a Pod event. Either way, you have a lot of words that are not `kubectl describe`, `kubectl get events` and similar investigations and their outcomes. No one can *guess* what is wrong with your setup without knowing what concrete experiments you have already tried

Comment: Add the commands you have tried so far to debug and their outputs. Also include the outputs from commands mentioned by mdaniel

Comment: Hi @Matt, the POD is gone... I cannot do describe or events using kubectl and events does not give the details of all the pods.

Comment: @mdaniel, the Pods were scaled to 20 and there was a load executed for these pods. After sometime few of the Pods recreated. This is the only operation done on the cluster.

Comment: "*When I say POD restart, it is getting deleted and created freshly*" - So its not being restarted, it's being recreated. Can you change every occurance of a word **restarted** with a word **recreated** in your question, where this is what you actually mean. Because this is misleading. `restarted != recreated` - these are two different things.

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Have edited my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically you need to check Pod's events ([here is a tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51931477/7427923) how to do it).

Keep in mind, that events retention period is too short (approximately 1h), and you may need to store them somewhere else. [Here is a good article](https://medium.com/@andrew.kaczynski/kubernetes-events-how-to-keep-historical-data-of-your-cluster-835d685cc45) how to do it with EFK stack

The most common reason of Pods recreation - Node unavailability.
If Pod's Node is not available, Kubernetes recreates the Pods in other nodes.

Comment: If the service is already running on a pod, I really don't see why a "node unavailable" error would occur. I think that in most likelihood, the app crashes (SEGV, uncaught exception, or similar) or it ran out of some resource (no disk space, out of memory).

Comment: Most of the time, PODs get killed because of "OOMKilled" event or the resources are not available

Answer (score 0):

If a Node that any pod is scheduled to dies (drains out), those Pods  are scheduled for deletion after a timeout period.

You can identify the reason for it by if the node that the pod was scheduled to was in a Ready state. Else the pod will go into a NotReady state and terminate after a period

Answer (score 0):

I am faicng the similiar issue with the pod recreate, with my situation experience, you can try this:

- check the host kernel log and make sure there is no OOM killer events(using command `dmesg -T | egrep -i 'killed process'`)
- make sure your container proccess with pid 1 not exit, when the pid 1 ended the pod will exit, and kubelet will auto start the pod

I am facing the pod restart with this 2 situation.